# Customizing Mathematica shortcuts with NeoQwertz keyboard layout

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, key-bindings

**Question:**

I want to use the Mathematica (currently version 13.2) shortcuts and use a NeoQwertz Keyboard layout (https://www.neo-layout.org/Layouts/neoqwertz/).

I know about the KeyEventTranslations.tr file, but I am not sure how to change stuff there in regards to the NeoQwertz layout, since I don't know how to describe the keys.

Specifically I want the `Superscript` and the `Fraction` to work with the usual keybinds `Crtl`+`6` and `Ctrl`+`/` (or on normal german keyboard `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`7`)

In general, is there any way to use key bindings in a outcome-based fashion, i.e. `Ctrl` + `/` would be whatever `Ctrl` + `whatever maps to /`?

Thanks :)

**What I tried:**

I tried changing stuff in the KeyEventTranslations.tr file, but VS Code said I don't have permissions to save. Giving me the option to save as admin seems to have worked, but I'm not sure since the new keybinds did work only sporadically and not consistently (I know strange huh).

Specifically I changed

`Item[KeyEvent["/", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Fraction"],`

to

`Item[KeyEvent["7", Modifiers -> {Control, Shift}], "Fraction"],`

since NeoQwertz doesn't mess with the numbers at the top of the keyboard, nor with Ctrl or Shift.